# Thumb-driven wireless trackball with a tilting scrollwheel

Tags: wireless, windows, mice, trackball

One of the most popular trackballs is the Logitech M570 Wireless Trackball.

[image]

The big feature missing from their product is a tilting scrollwheel so the user can scroll horizontally.

Is there a thumb-driven Windows-compatible wireless trackball with a tilting scrollwheel that anyone can recommend?

Comment: Can't help with that, but while you're looking: I click the scroll wheel to get the "pan" functionality, then use the trackball to scroll any/every direction, including horizontal. I have the M570. Wheel clicking that way works in many applications.

Answer (score 1):

I found two thumb-driven wireless trackballs with tilt wheels that are compatible with Windows:

- [Logitech MX ERGO](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-ergo-wireless-trackball-mouse)
- [ELECOM M-XT3DRBK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016QCPNUW)